# Trouble getting AngularJS app to start

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-2013

I looked at AngularJS this summer and I am trying to port my old plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/uhwXJ456OyRFQbXnz1rS?p=info to Visual Studios.

I made a new project and I have a HomeController. I then made a Home view, and added the file Index.cshtml to it. After that I just added my files in and now I am having trouble getting it to start up.

I get the errors "Angular is not defined", and "Cannot read property 'module' of undefined".

In my Index.cshtml I have the following.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title>League of Dataz</title>
    <!-- SCROLLS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/style.css" />

    <!-- SPELLS -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/angularjs.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="HomeController">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <a href="#home">Home</a>
                <a href="#login">Login</a>
                <a href="#account">Accounts</a>
                <a href="#n00b">BrokenURL</a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="view" ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I believe I had to do some weird work-arounds in order for this to work on Plunker, and now I am having trouble piecing together how it should actually be coded in the real world.

I stuck the VS Web Express 2013 project on this Zip site if anyone needs a better picture of what is going on, it's a tiny file since I can't even get it to run yet: [LeagueData](https://www.zipshare.com/download/eyJhcmNoaXZlSWQiOiI1MzZiOGM1ZC1hNWZiLTQ4YzgtYTRjOS0yY2ZmYmYyY2UwNzciLCJlbWFpbCI6ImFhbmRlcnM1MEBnbWFpbC5jb20ifQ==)

Comment: Post your Angular code, not a link to a zip file.

Comment: Do one thing post your code on Plunker as you given above link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your paths. Angular being undefined means that the JS lib isn't loading. When you pull it up in the browser, open the web developer tools and check the network - see where it's trying to load the javascript file from.

Comment: Wow, you are right, I messed up my angular.js pathway (I said angularjs.js on accident). >.< It's running fine now! At least I setup it up right for the most part :)